# separating asynchronous HttpClient and Ui thread Winrt?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying download json data from a rest service and all i'm doing 
is for a button click navigating to a new page and in the new page i'm 
using async methods to download data.

But still the UI gets stuck ... the ui get's stuck in the first page until the download is completed.. i've tried using async on PageLoaded event .. and in many other loaded events on other elements of the page .. how do I separate them both?

```
 private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //download helper
        IWebService _downloadClient = new DownloadClient();
        var _JsonString = _downloadClient.GetDataAsync(uri);
        //Json to Object Converter
        IJsonDeserializer _deserializer = new JsonToObject();
        ApodProp = _deserializer.DesrializeTo<RootObject>(_JsonString);


        apobinding(); //sets some textblocks to the data downloaded
    }
```

The Whole Page doesn't appear until the download is completed and i didn't use any await because the internal methods in the download client use async and await keywords ..

Download Client Edited :

```
public Task<string> GetDataAsync(string uri)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            try
            {
                using (HttpClient Client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    Task<HttpResponseMessage> _result = Client.GetAsync(uri);
                    HttpResponseMessage responseData = _result.Result;
                    return await responseData.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException)
            {

                MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Http exception");
               await md.ShowAsync();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

UPDATE:
Even now my UI doesnt show up until the download is complete.

```
 protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
        await MyTask();    
    }
```

myTask:

```
private async Task MyTask()
        {
            IApiService _apiProvider = new RestClient.ApiService.NasaAPOD();
            var formattableString = _apiProvider.GetFormattableApiCallString("api_key;concept_tags");

            IParameterFiller filler = new ParameterFiller();
            var uri = filler.FillParameters(formattableString, "I3pA7RdSKvrER6hm6f51BhWzCmoJM6Alq6BjbbEu;true");

            IWebService _downloadClient = new DownloadClient();
            var _JsonString = await _downloadClient.GetDataAsync(uri);

            IJsonDeserializer _deserializer = new JsonToObject();
            ApodProp = _deserializer.DesrializeTo<RootObject>(_JsonString);


            apobinding();
        }
```

**FINALLY NAILED IT**

```
await Task.Run(()=> { MyTask();  }  ); 
        apobinding();
```

that's all that is all you need ...

now to the concept part ... 
In windows there is a rule that the controls must be accessed from the thread 
they were created from and any code that contains the ui controls must be run on the same thread unless you explicitly specify it ...

In the first case the the ui thread i.e apobinding was along with the downloading code so the whole UI thread was freezed .

In order to get responsiveness I had to put the downloading on to a separate process.

then i've experimented with placing the ui inside the MyTask and task.run .. both ways it resulted in a similar o/p .. yes as you guessed it according to the windows rule of threads if ui control is accesse from any other thread than it was created will result in **Crash Crash Crash**

I had a real tough time with the responsiveness ... but don't forget the user will uninstall if your application is unresponsive be it VS or Windows or Mac or Linux or any other great software.. so make the UI responsive and become the best (being sarcastic .. there is a lot more to do).

Comment: This works (save for it blocks the page)? I'd guess _JsonString is actually Task type. Anyway put await before GetDataAsync call and done..

Comment: What does `DownloadClient.GetDataAsync` return?

Comment: no it returns a string .. and i pass the string to desrializer

Comment: oh ! my bad My downloadclient wasnt asynchronous.

Comment: Need some help .. I've made the interfaces to act as a base for the download client .. the interface isnt allowing me to declare the method as a async method ... this has been causing a lot of nproblems in my other classes as well ... what is the potential solution for this?  when i declare it as async it gives an error saying that 'async' is not a valid item for this.          neither this              async void GetDataAsync<T>(string uri);  nor this async string GetDataAsync(string uri); works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments you say that `_downloadClient.GetDataAsync` isn't async and the interface method isn't either. Two options:

1. Make the interface method return `Task`.
2. Put the synchronous download on the thread-pool: `await Task.Run(() => _downloadClient.GetDataAsync(uri));`. This is a quick fix. If there are few downloads running at the same time then this is not a perf or memory problem and is a valid fix.

Comment: new problem my updated downloadclient is above, now it's return type is task and i cant mark it async ... but my httpclient needs an async call what is the solution to this problem?

Comment: You should be able to make GetDataAsync async. Why not? Then, it should work as expected.

Comment: Oh yes ! may be it was a mistake by me again ... So if start using the the thread pool can i call it everywhere int he project and is there any time limit that would effect the performance ... since i'm targeting phone devices i need to consume as less memory as possible

Comment: If your method is now async, which seems to be the case, you don't need Task.Run anymore. No concerns there.

Comment: My button is still in the pressed mode until the task is completed ... as i'm navigating to this page from a another page click and i'm calling the task in onnavigatedto method... the button stays in the pressed state for about 3 sec and the page popsup with the data loaded .. I've added myTask in the question above.

Comment: Hm, looks fine. Comment out individual lines until the UI freeze stops. Or, pause the debugger during the freeze and look at what's on the stack. Report back with those findings and post the relevant code that caused the freeze.

Comment: 1. the OnNavigatedTo Method is stacked upon the Previous page button call method . 2. Then   MyTask is stacked upon the OnNaviagtedTo and the internal calls are stacked and removed .. i didnt find a way to see when the ui was freezing because nothing happened until the cal was returned to OnNavigatedTo

Comment: I've gone through similar problem the download time looks same 3sec-5sec(assuming you have fast connection).. and this is the time where the ui goes unresponsive ...

Comment: After Some Reading I've found out that Something called a dispatcher is required to this kind of stuff .. pls guide me if u can